# CSS: How to make div adapt to image size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass

I have implemented CSS status that allows to see if the user is online or not:
[image]
This is the CSS code:

```
.status-circle-online {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 60, 0);
  border: 2px solid white;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This is the html code:

```
  <div>
    <img
      src={profileImageSrc}
      className="rounded-circle ml-3"
    />
    <div
      className={`status-circle-${online_or_offline_signal} cursor-pointer`}
    />
  </div>
```

The problem is that when I reduce window size, the status signal is no longer where it should be:
[image]

[image]

Any idea how to make it "stick" to the image?

Comment: position:relative on its parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without seeing more of your code. But you could try adding `position: relative;` to the containing div, and then for the red circle use percentages instead of pixels for `right` and `bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

Position the parent div `relative` and then the absolute values of the status indicator will be relative to that container:

```css
.status-photo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.status-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.status-photo .status {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 60, 0);
  border: 2px solid white;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-photo">
  <img
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGVyc29ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60"
  />
  <div
    class="status"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were helpful. But, a more responsive way to do it is to user percentages:

```
.status-photo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.status-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.status-photo .status-online {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 60, 0);
  border: 1px solid white;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}
```